# How can i add download link in menu item in wordpress main menu?

Tags: wordpress, download, e-commerce, menuitem

I am try to set download link on main navigation menu menu item in wordpress.

Comment: Nothing found so what to try.

Comment: I have one idea. I am add manually custom code for that in header file. But this is not right solution.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the easiest way to go is to zip your file, upload it via media library, then create custom link menu item and insert link to your zipped file. That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and created the plugin "Download Documents Menu" to solve it.

After installing it through the link https://wordpress.org/plugins/download-documents-menu/, you can add a custom link to your menu and check the option "Download".

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29902112)